# Passing query string from #new to #create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, controller, state

I am trying to update my inventory after a Stripe transaction

**routes**:

```
  get 'product/:size' => 'charges#new'
  resources :charges
```

ex: localhost:3000/product/32

**controller**

```
  def new
    @product = Product.find_by(size: params[:size])
  end

  def create
    @amount = 500
    @product = Product.find_by(size: params[:size])
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => 'example@stripe.com',
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
    )


    @product.update_attribute(:status, "sold")

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path


  end
end
```

This returns

```
undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass
```

After testing through trial and error, I believe that the problem is that Rails is not finding [:size] in params, thus the instance variable is not being instantiated.

What must I do?

Comment: could you print `@product` before `@product.update_attribute....` ?

Comment: It doesn't print anything. The console output is the same with or without @artmees

Comment: could you `print params[:size]`

Comment: Neither @artmees ......

Comment: how are you passing the params from the view to the controller ?

Comment: I am not. The params I'm getting in #new are from the URL, I'd like to pass that to #create @artmees

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69858/discussion-between-shiva-and-artmees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the :size param into your form so that it is passed along to the create action during the POST. You can include it in your form using `hidden_field_tag`:

```
<%= form ... do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :size, params[:size] %>

  Other form inputs....
<% end %>
```